# Explicit cast to r-value reference does not clear ambiguity

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, overloading

Regarding the following code:

```
void foo( int in )
{
  std::cout << "no ref" << std::endl;
}

void foo( int&& in )
{
  std::cout << "ref&&" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{ 
  foo( static_cast<int&&>(1) );

  return 0;
}
```

I wonder why the call to `foo( static_cast< int&& >(1) )` is ambiguous:

```
error: call to 'foo' is ambiguous
  foo( static_cast<int&&>(1) );
  ^~~
```

Because of the explicit cast to `int&&`, I expected that `void foo( int&& in )` will be called.

Comment: The expression `1` already *is* an rvalue.

Comment: Probably the same reason `void foo(const int& in)` would be ambiguous - both functions can take the same type without needing to convert it.

Comment: @MarkRansom `void foo( int&& in )` is preferred over `void foo(const int& in)` if it is an rvalue.

Comment: @NathanOliver there are *so* many corner cases in C++, I learned something new today. Thank you!

Comment: @MarkRansom No problem.  I find it hard to keep them all straight myself.

Comment: I didn't even know you could call `static_cast` to an r-value. I figured that's what `std::move` is for...

Comment: @GuyKogus `std::move` is implemented precisely as `std::static_cast<SomeType&&>`